# Is Java 2d int array considerer generic? Why?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, types

I knew Java array of primitive ints (`int[] arr = new int[5]`) is not considered generic object, therefore it can't be provided as argument to either `Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` or `ArrayList.toArray(T[] a)`.

However I just found out 2d array of primitive ints can be taken as argument to above mentioned methods! Code is attached below.

```
int[][] points = new int[3][3];
Arrays.sort(points, (a, b) -> a[1] - b[1]);

List<int[]> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(new int[]{1,3,5});
list2.add(new int[]{2});
int[][] array2 = list2.toArray(new int[5][5]);
for(int[] i : array2)
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i));
```

How is that possible? Is it because that a 2d int array is seen as array of primitive int array where the inner array itself not primitive? What is the design behind this behaviour?

Comment: I suspect that it's because `int` is a primitive type, but `int[]` is a class.

Comment: If any of the answer on this question solved your issue, feel free to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Arrays::sort`, like many other methods that accept generic types, is overloaded to support primitive types, see [the JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html). In fact, there are 18 variations of `Arrays::sort`:

```
static void sort(byte[] a)
static void sort(byte[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
static void sort(char[] a)
static void sort(char[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
static void sort(double[] a)
static void sort(double[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
static void sort(float[] a)
static void sort(float[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
static void sort(int[] a)
static void sort(int[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
static void sort(long[] a)
static void sort(long[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
static void sort(Object[] a)
static void sort(Object[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
static void sort(short[] a)
static void sort(short[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
static <T> void sort(T[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

As you can see, all of them except the ones taking `Comparator`s are overloaded to accept all primitives as well as a generic array type.

As for why `static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` accepts an object of type `int[][]`, but **not** an an object of type `int[]`: `int[][]` is an array of `int[]`, which is a type that extends `Object`, unlike `int`. `int[][]` is an array of objects, not an array of primitives.

Comment: I know int[] is an object but didn't know int[] is of the class `[I`. Do you mean that the second to last sort() accepts int[] as T[] (which can be seen as `[I`) ? Is that how it works?

Comment: It does not accept `int[]`, it accepts `int[][]` though. See my edited answer for why it does.

Answer (score 1):

**How is that possible?**

This is possible because the overloaded method that is invoked is: `static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`. In this invokation, the `T` will be equivalent to `[I`.

**Is it because that a 2d int array is seen as array of primitive int array where the inner array itself not primitive?**

You are correct in noting that the inner array is not a primitive. The inner array is actually a class: `[I`. Infact, if you run the following code, you are deterministically prove that it is indeed a class.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] i = new int[]{1,2};
    System.out.println(i.getClass());

    int[][] i2d = new int[][]{{1},{2},{3}};
    System.out.println( i2d.getClass() );
    System.out.println( i2d[0].getClass() );
}
```

In fact, the class that `i2d[0]` represents the same class that `i` represents.

**What is the design behind this behaviour?**

The design is that an array has to be an object. The array is going to be initialised on the heap and thus we need a pointer to it.

Comment: `[I` is a type encoding. It is not the name of a class. The type is still written as `int[]`.